# What are all these strange firefox processes?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I just updated to Firefox 57 on Ubuntu and now when I run `ps -ef|grep firefox` I get a lot of strange process messages and I'm wondering if this is normal.

> `gunnl 9048 6040 8 08:29 ? 00:01:42 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox gunnl 9732 9048 0 08:42 ? 00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -intPrefs 5:50|6:-1|18:0|28:1000|34:20|35:5|36:10|45:128|46:10000|51:0|53:400|54:1|55:0|56:0|61:0|62:120|63:120|98:2|99:1|114:5000|124:0|126:0|137:10000|162:24|163:32768|165:0|166:2|174:4|178:1048576|179:100|180:5000|182:600|183:4|184:1|193:3|206:60000| -boolPrefs 1:0|2:0|4:0|26:1|27:1|30:0|33:1|37:1|38:0|39:0|40:0|43:1|44:1|47:0|48:0|49:0|50:0|52:0|57:1|58:1|59:0|60:1|64:1|65:1|66:0|67:1|68:1|69:0|70:1|73:0|74:0|77:1|78:1|82:1|83:1|84:1|85:0|86:0|88:0|89:0|90:1|91:0|92:1|95:1|97:0|100:1|101:0|108:0|113:0|116:0|118:1|119:1|121:1|125:0|127:0|129:0|131:1|132:1|138:1|139:0|140:1|142:0|153:1|160:0|161:0|164:1|167:0|169:1|171:1|172:0|177:0|181:1|186:0|187:0|188:0|189:1|190:0|191:1|192:1|195:1|198:0|199:0|200:1|201:1|202:0|203:1|204:1|205:1|207:0|208:0|210:0|218:1|219:1|220:0|221:0|222:0| -stringPrefs 3:7;release|96:0;|141:3;1.0|158:332;  ¼½¾ǃː??։֊׃״؉؊٪۔܁܂܃܄ᅟ?᜵           ???‐’․‧??????? ‹›⁁⁄⁒ ⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚?⅜⅝⅞⅟∕∶⎮╱⧶⧸⫻⫽⿰⿱⿲⿳⿴⿵⿶⿷⿸⿹⿺⿻　。〔〕〳゠ㅤ㈝㈞㎮㎯㏆㏟꞉︔︕︿﹝﹞?．／｡ﾠ???￼�|159:4;high| -schedulerPrefs 0001,2 -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 9048 true tab gunnl 9788 9048 5 08:42 ? 00:00:25 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -intPrefs 5:50|6:-1|18:0|28:1000|34:20|35:5|36:10|45:128|46:10000|51:0|53:400|54:1|55:0|56:0|61:0|62:120|63:120|98:2|99:1|114:5000|124:0|126:0|137:10000|162:24|163:32768|165:0|166:2|174:4|178:1048576|179:100|180:5000|182:600|183:4|184:1|193:3|206:60000| -boolPrefs 1:0|2:0|4:0|26:1|27:1|30:0|33:1|37:1|38:0|39:0|40:0|43:1|44:1|47:0|48:0|49:0|50:0|52:0|57:1|58:1|59:0|60:1|64:1|65:1|66:0|67:1|68:1|69:0|70:1|73:0|74:0|77:1|78:1|82:1|83:1|84:1|85:0|86:0|88:0|89:0|90:1|91:0|92:1|95:1|97:0|100:1|101:0|108:0|113:0|116:0|118:1|119:1|121:1|125:0|127:0|129:0|131:1|132:1|138:1|139:0|140:1|142:0|153:1|160:0|161:0|164:1|167:0|169:1|171:1|172:0|177:0|181:1|186:0|187:0|188:0|189:1|190:0|191:1|192:1|195:1|198:0|199:0|200:1|201:1|202:0|203:1|204:1|205:1|207:0|208:0|210:0|218:1|219:1|220:0|221:0|222:0| -stringPrefs 3:7;release|96:0;|141:3;1.0|158:332;  ¼½¾ǃː??։֊׃״؉؊٪۔܁܂܃܄ᅟ?᜵           ???‐’․‧??????? ‹›⁁⁄⁒ ⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚?⅜⅝⅞⅟∕∶⎮╱⧶⧸⫻⫽⿰⿱⿲⿳⿴⿵⿶⿷⿸⿹⿺⿻　。〔〕〳゠ㅤ㈝㈞㎮㎯㏆㏟꞉︔︕︿﹝﹞?．／｡ﾠ???￼�|159:4;high| -schedulerPrefs 0001,2 -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 9048 true tab gunnl 10125 7334 0 08:50 pts/1 00:00:00 grep --color=auto firefox`

Does anyone know if this is normal?

Comment: Please consider fixing your formatting. I highly doubt there wasn't a single line break in this.

Comment: +Seth Actually there aren't many line breaks in that. It's only 4 lines. On my system, those long firefox process lines are 1430 characters long.

Comment: One worry I had about this was that with the obvious naming of those options that browser preferences were being leaked into the process table. I tested this by creating a profile with very different preferences, but it didn't change anything in those long string values.  The values for gunnl's firefox sub-process options above are identical to those on my system for what it's worth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like you're using multiprocess support in Firefox. This feature is called Electrolysis (aka e10s) and it is supposed to improve security (sandboxing) and performance. More details can be found on Mozilla wiki: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis